# Windows Server 2012 - one user logging on many computers

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-essentials

I am a newby to Windows Server World. I want to setup company's network (around 7 computers and 15 employees) like this:
- all computers joined to my domain
- every employee having his own user account
- every employee being able to log into any company computer with his domain credentials
- every logged in user having access to his personal files from any computer within domain (and, if possible, also having his own settings such us dekstop icons, dekstop wallpaper etc - to create impression that he is always on the same computer even though it is a different one in a different office).
- have a printer connected to all computers via network

My question is - is it possible with Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials? And if so - I would be grateful for any hits as I don't even know where to start looking for answers.

Cheers,
Kate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. It's a very standard setup. If you don't know where to start, I'd suggest hiring someone if you need this done quickly and/or correctly.

This site is intended for people who are already, to some degree, systems administrators in a professional position, and it doesn't sound like you are - which is why my advice is to find someone qualified.

Comment: Does Essentials support all that (folder redirection, etc)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Yep. For a single domain environment you can basically think of it like plain ol' Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

After more research I found that the answer to my quiestion is Roaming User Profiles. In case any one else is facing similar problem.
And here is how to configure it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx